# WebService wsdl response

Tags: c#

A method in my WebService returns a DataSet containing 5 `variables`. 2 of them are `string`, 1 `int` and the 2 others `boolean`.

After publishing the WebService, that specific response in the `wsdl` looks like: `<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="myMethodResult">`

Now, people consuming the WebService ask me if I can change it somehow so the `wsdl` ends up looking something like this:

```
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="variable1" type="s:string" />
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="variable2" type="s:string" />
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="variable3" type="s:int" />
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="variable4" type="s:boolean" />
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="variable5" type="s:boolean" />
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a WCF web service, you can create an attribute that implements [`IContractBehavior`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.icontractbehavior.aspx) and [`IWsdlExportExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iwsdlexportextension.aspx) as described in [this](http://thorarin.net/blog/post/2010/08/08/Controlling-WSDL-minOccurs-with-WCF.aspx) post.

Here is the excerpt of it:

> ```
> void IWsdlExportExtension.ExportContract(WsdlExporter exporter, WsdlContractConversionContext context)
> {
>     foreach (var operation in context.Contract.Operations)
>     {
>         var inputMessage = operation.Messages.
>             Where(m => m.Direction == MessageDirection.Input).First();
>         var parameters = operation.SyncMethod.GetParameters();
>
>         for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
>         {
>             object[] attributes = parameters[i].GetCustomAttributes(
>                 typeof(OptionalAttribute), false);
>
>             if (attributes.Length == 0)
>             {
>                 // The parameter has no [Optional] attribute, add it
>                 // to the list of parameters that we need to adjust
>                 // the XML schema for later on.
>                 _requiredParameter.Add(new RequiredMessagePart()
>                     {
>                         Namespace = inputMessage.Body.Parts[i].Namespace,
>                         Message = operation.Name,
>                         Name = inputMessage.Body.Parts[i].Name
>                     });
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> void IWsdlExportExtension.ExportEndpoint(WsdlExporter exporter, WsdlEndpointConversionContext context)
> {
>     foreach (var p in _requiredParameter)
>     {
>         var schemas = exporter.GeneratedXmlSchemas.Schemas(p.Namespace);
>
>         foreach (XmlSchema schema in schemas)
>         {
>             var message = (XmlSchemaElement)schema.Elements[p.XmlQualifiedName];
>             var complexType = (XmlSchemaComplexType)message.ElementSchemaType;
>             var sequence = (XmlSchemaSequence)complexType.Particle;
>
>             foreach (XmlSchemaElement item in sequence.Items)
>             {
>                 if (item.Name == p.Name)
>                 {
>                     item.MinOccurs = 1;
>                     item.MinOccursString = "1";
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

with thanks to the author *Marcel Veldhuizen*.

Comment: Sorry for not being that accurate with the info provided. Not a WCF WS but an regular SOAP one.

Comment: Not that simple then. Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961112/how-to-make-a-dotnet-webservice-set-minoccurs-1-on-a-string-value) SO answer. You can always change it manually or write some code that updates the text yourself..